# Visual Studio forms does not have a properly functioning UI Tab

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Whenever I try to add a forms window to my visual c++ application, I go to the UI Tab in Project --> Add New Item --> UI--> and i look for Windows Form, but I find

> addmc++usercontrol

for some reason, I have tried updating Visual Studio, however my problem was not resoved, my current version is 15.5.6.

[image: UI Tab]

Comment: What kind of application do you have? Console, Win32, MFC, managed C++, something else?

Comment: I have a Win32 application

Comment: If you want to add a form to a win32 application then you should have a resource containing a dialog.

Comment: It is way easier to do it this way, I have seen windows forms being created with msvcp 2017 using this method on numerous occasions, and even on older msvcp's like 2013, 2015. 2008

Answer (score 0):

Launch your VS 2017 Installer and in the Desktop development with C++ select to the right the Optional component "C++ /CLI Support"